Docker/Traefik container communication
Previously, I was using nginx where a codesample like this would work fine:
http://api:80/whatever
however recently i have switched to traefik, and now im having issues
name: steal

services:
  api:
    build: ./Docker/steal/api
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://api:8080/status" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s

  discord:
    build: ./Docker/steal/discord
    depends_on:
      traefik:
        condition: service_healthy

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        apk add --no-cache curl &&
        traefik --api.insecure=true --providers.docker=true --entrypoints.web.address=:80 --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://traefik:8080/api/rawdata" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s

I have tried http://api:80, http://localhost:80, http://localhost, etc and still haven't been able to connect. The message i receive is " All connection attempts failed"
Any idea how I can fix this? I know its probably some small traefik setting I am overlooking, but any help is appreciated

Well, what's the issue? Can the hostname be resolved to an IP, is the port open, can your client connect to Traefik? Check Traefik debug log and Traefik access log to see whats happening during requests.
I would not hack the Traefik command as container signals might not get through to Traefik anymore. Use included wget instead of curl.
And maybe remove all the healthchecks for early debugging.

@bluepuma77 Hey, thanks for the response. Yes, I can connect to Traefik and localhost perfectly fine from my client, it seems to only be an issue when a different container of mine (not running on Traefik, but in the same compose) tries to connect through a python script. Access logs shows nothing for the python request either, which I found pretty weird. Will keep trying to sort out something

From what it looks like, whenever I use localhost:80 it doesn't even access traefik and it returns "All connection attempts failed". Whenever I use traefik:80 it returns a 404 error. Im guessing its something to do with the networking configuration on localhost, i've tried tinkering with docker networks + various traefik configurations but haven't had much luck yet
